# Aggregation by time

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I want to aggregate an attribute from a mysql database based on a time interval. Here is my data structure with some example data:

**events table**

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id |        start        |         end         |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2017-01-22 14:00:00 | 2017-01-22 17:00:00 |
|  2 | 2017-01-22 15:00:00 | 2017-01-22 18:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**bookings table**

```
+----+----------+--------------+--------+
| id | event_id | person_count | status |
+----+----------+--------------+--------+
|  1 |        1 |            5 |      1 |
|  2 |        1 |            4 |      1 |
|  3 |        1 |            6 |      1 |
|  4 |        2 |            3 |      1 |
|  5 |        2 |            4 |      1 |
|  6 |        2 |            5 |      0 |
+----+----------+--------------+--------+
```

I'm looking for a way to find out how many persons ( SUM of bookings.person_count) attending to an event within a 15 minutes time interval where the booking status is 1. So the output of the query should look like this:

```
+---------------------+--------------------+
|        date         | person_count_total |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 14:00:00 |                 15 |
| 2017-01-22 14:15:00 |                 15 |
| 2017-01-22 14:30:00 |                 15 |
| 2017-01-22 14:45:00 |                 15 |
| 2017-01-22 15:00:00 |                 22 |
| 2017-01-22 15:15:00 |                 22 |
| 2017-01-22 15:30:00 |                 22 |
| 2017-01-22 15:45:00 |                 22 |
| 2017-01-22 16:00:00 |                 22 |
| 2017-01-22 16:15:00 |                 22 |
| 2017-01-22 16:30:00 |                 22 |
| 2017-01-22 16:45:00 |                 22 |
| 2017-01-22 17:00:00 |                 22 |
| 2017-01-22 17:15:00 |                  7 |
| 2017-01-22 17:30:00 |                  7 |
| 2017-01-22 17:45:00 |                  7 |
| 2017-01-22 18:00:00 |                  7 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Is there any way to achieve this in mysql only? Current solution is looping over all 15 minutes intervalt betweend first start and last end in the php application. But as this creates a lot datapoints and the performance is not good because every datapoint means one query.

Comment: "this creates a lot of datapoints" . . . don'w you want data for all the data points?  How do you avoid that?

Comment: I mean the creation of the data via the php script costs a lot. Because every datapoint means one query.

Comment: You sum is incorrect at 17:00 it should be 22. as both 1 and 2 are present at that moment @lasagne

Comment: You are right. I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate rows between the dates and then make a JOIN with bookings table, something like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.date,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN b.status = 1 THEN person_count
    END) person_count_total
FROM
    bookings b
        INNER JOIN
    events e ON b.event_id = e.id
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        (SELECT 
                    MIN(start)
                FROM
                    events) + INTERVAL 15 * (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a)) MINUTE AS Date
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS d
) t ON t.date BETWEEN e.start AND e.end
GROUP BY t.date
;
```

In case the difference between min and max date in events is larger, you can simple add another cross join to accommodate more range and add a `10000 * e.a` .. and so on

```
+---------------------+--------------------+
| date                | person_count_total |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 14:00:00 | 15                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 14:15:00 | 15                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 14:30:00 | 15                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 14:45:00 | 15                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 15:00:00 | 22                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 15:15:00 | 22                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 15:30:00 | 22                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 15:45:00 | 22                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 16:00:00 | 22                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 16:15:00 | 22                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 16:30:00 | 22                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 16:45:00 | 22                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 17:00:00 | 22                 | 
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 17:15:00 | 7                  |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 17:30:00 | 7                  |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 17:45:00 | 7                  |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-22 18:00:00 | 7                  |
+---------------------+--------------------+
```